# Cálculos com Less css

Tags: css, less

Tenho o seguinte mixin:

```
.mixin-loop (@i) when (@i > 0)  {
    .navigation .dropdown > li:nth-child(@{i}) {
        .vendor(animation, new-menu 200ms ease-in-out forwards);
    }
}
```

Sendo esse .vendor apenas um mixin para vendors:

```
.vendor(@property, @value) {
    -webkit-@{property}: @value;
     -moz-@{property}: @value;
       -ms-@{property}: @value;
            @{property}: @value;
}
```

Como eu faço para adicionar + 200ms nesse código a cada volta do loop?

Answer (score 0):

Basta iterar um multiplicador:

```
.vendor(@property, @value) {
  -webkit-@{property}: @value;
     -moz-@{property}: @value;
      -ms-@{property}: @value;
          @{property}: @value;
}

.mixin-loop (@i) when (@i > 0)  {
  .mixin-loop(@i - 1);
  .navigation .dropdown > li:nth-child(@{i}) {
    .vendor(animation, new-menu (200ms * @i) ease-in-out forwards);
  }
}

nav{
  .mixin-loop(8);
}
```